# Switching monitors when Steam Controller is turned on

Tags: multiple-monitors, steam, hdmi, xrandr, gamepad

I own a Steam Link, but the input lag is annoying in some FPS games, so I got a HDMI cable to connect my PC with the TV. When I sit in front of the TV I want to turn the SC on and have Big Picture start up on the TV. My PC display and the TV have different resolutions, thus I do not want to have the TV screen mirrored all the time.

So I am looking for a way to turn on the TV display (probably through a xrandr bash script). My problem right now is this:

How can I trigger a script upon Steam Controller On-Button?

I did not find anything on Google and have no clue where to start searching. Would this maybe be possible through a udev rule?

Bonus: Can the HDMI additionally request the TV's focus when another channel/input is selected on the TV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this Python standalone Steam Controller driver: https://github.com/ynsta/steamcontroller

There are a few example script on how to get button events and set up a callback. I just set up a callback for the home button and launch steam from there. The only issue is, that you can't have that script running while steam runs because the standalone driver will capture all controller events, but I wanted steam to control the controller (just start steam and close the script).

So I have:

- main.py: controls all scripts, waits for button_callback.py result then launches start_steam.py, when that exits restart button_callback.py
- button_callback.py: waits for a home button press, then exits
- start_steam.py: activates tv via xrandr, switches audio sink via pacmd to hdmi, waits for steam close, deactivates tv, reverts audio